# How do i sort a list with first and last name by the last names

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list like `L=['john fwtiou','nick dallas','kostas papadopoulos']`
How do I sort it by the last names? the right should be first `nick dallas` then `john fwtiou` and then `kostas papadopoulos`

Comment: What language are you using? Please include the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda name: name.split()[1])
['nick dallas', 'john fwtiou', 'kostas papadopoulos']
```

Comment: this is great. but in some cases there may be a middle name included so I modified to use `sorted(l, key=lambda name: name.split()[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 L = ['john fwtiou','nick dallas','kostas papadopoulos']
 L_sorted = sorted(L, key=lambda name: name[name.find(' ')+1])
 print(L_sorted)
```

Explanation: `name[name.find(' ')+1]` finds the first letter after the space. The `sorted` function then takes the list and sorts it with that as a custom key.

Comment: What if two last names start with the same letter?